# How to write a program that shows WLAN access points using Java

Tags: java, wifi

As title, i want to write a program to detect WLAN AP and from there can detect how many host connected to certain wlan AP. Which language provide this function? Any idea where to search from, i have no idea on networking.

Answer (score 0):

Either by wrapping a command line tool that does that or by using native code. And this depends on the operation system. There is no native Java API that does this, IMHO.